# How do you prove this theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

The theorem I have to prove is

```
 Let F be a field. A nonzero polynomial f(x) is reducible in F(x) if and only if f(x) can be written as the product of two polynomials of lower degree.
```

It's an if and only if proof so I know that there are two parts to the proof. My book proves the first part- First Assume that f(x) is reducible. Now I have to do the second part-Assume f(x) can be written as the product of two polynomials of lower degree.

My initial thought was to let f(x) = g(x)*h(x) and do cases...

Case 1 : g(x) or h(x) is an associate

Case 2: g(x) or h(x) is a constant

But I am now sure how to go about proving these cases.

Comment: what's your definition of reducible?

Comment: @Exodd the book's definition of irreducible is it's only divisors are its associates and the nonzero constants (units). and the definition of reducible is simple not irreducible

Answer (score 1):

$g(x),h(x)$ are divisors of $f(x)$, but their degree are lower than $f(x)$.

That means that neither of them are associates of $f(x)$, since the associates of a polynomial have its same degree.

If $g(x)$ is a constant, then $h(x)$ is associated to $f(x)$, absurd. And the same goes for $h(x)$

Comment: if g(x), h(x) are divisors of f(x) doesn't that mean their degrees are less than or equal to f(x)? not just less than?

Comment: yes, but in your theorem you have "two polynomials of lower degree."